# Proof by resolution - Artificial Intelligence

Tags: logic, artificial-intelligence, resolution, conjunctive-normal-form

I'm working with an exercise where I need to show that `KB |= ~D`.

And I know that the Knowledge Base is:

```
 - (B v ¬C) => ¬A
 - (¬A v D) => B
 - A ∧ C
```

After converting to CNF:

```
A ∧ C ∧ (¬A v ¬B) ∧ (¬A v C) ∧ (A v B) ∧ (B v ¬D)
```

So now I have converted to CNF but from there, I don't know how to go any further. Would appreciate any help. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The general resolution rule is that, for any two clauses
(that is, disjunctions of literals)

```
P_1 v ... v P_n
```

and

```
Q_1 v ... v Q_m
```

in your CNF such that there is i and j with P_i and Q_j being the negation of each other,
you can add a new clause

```
P_1 v ... v P_{i-1} v P_{i+1} ... v P_n v Q_1 v ... v Q_{j-1} v Q_{j+1} ... v Q_m
```

This is just a rigorous way to say that you can form a new clause by joining two of them, minus a literal with opposite "signs" in each.

For example

```
(A v ¬B)∧(B v ¬C)
```

is equivalent to

```
(A v ¬B)∧(B v ¬C)∧(A v ¬C),
```

by joining the two clauses while removing the opposites `B` and `¬B`, obtaining `A v ¬C`.

Another example is

```
A∧(¬A v ¬C)
```

which is equivalent to

```
A∧(¬A v ¬C) ∧ ¬C.
```

since `A` counts as a clause with a single literal (`A` itself). So the two clauses are joined, while `A` and `¬A` are removed, yielding a new clause `¬C`.

Applying this to your problem, we can resolve `A` and `¬A v ¬B`, obtaining `¬B`.
We then resolve this new clause `¬B` with `B v ¬D`, obtaining `¬D`.

Because the CNF is a conjunction, the fact that it holds means that every clause in it holds. That is to say, the CNF implies all of its clauses. Since `¬D` is one of its clauses, `¬D` is implied by the CNF. Since the CNF is equivalent to the original KB, the KB implies `¬D`.